# В чем отличие обычных Java streams от стримов Reactor\WebFlux?

Tags: java, spring, java-stream, reactive

Пытаюсь разобраться в реактивном программировании. В сети много материалов, но какие-то ниточки к полному пониманию от меня ускользают, поэтому решил задать вопрос тут. Собственно Java-стримы, которые появились в 8 версии это по сути как струя воды из под крана, только в нашем случае это течение каких-то данных, которые мы можем преобразовать(фильтрация и тд). В стримах можно задействовать многопоточность(parallelStream) и тогда данные будут "течь" в стримах в нескольких потоках, что позволит быстрее их преобразовать.

Но вот, что такое реактивный стрим? В книгах и сети его сравнивают с конвейером сборки. То есть данные идут по конвейеру и "сборщики"(реактивные методы-операторы) с ними что-то делают. И это похоже на обычные стримы, где мы также колдуем с данными. Не совсем понятно также является ли реактивный поток Mono\Flux многопоточным, или это все один поток.

Чем отличается реактивный стрим от обычного и какую пользу даст его использование?

Comment: тут подробно ответили на подобный вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52820232/difference-between-infinite-java-stream-and-reactor-flux (конкретно https://stackoverflow.com/a/52823631 )

Comment: @ViktorFridman Спасибо!